# Is there a way to rewrite this basic function so I'm not repeating the same lines twice?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, loops

```js
const body = document.querySelector( `body` );

function getRandomNumber( max ) {
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * max )
}
function getRandomRGB() {
  const colors = [];
  
  for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    const  n = getRandomNumber( 100 + 1 );
    
    colors.push( n );
  }
  return `rgb(${ colors.join( '%,' )}%)`; 
}
function changeRGB() {
  const divs = body.querySelectorAll( `div` );
  
  for( let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
    divs[ i ].style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
    divs[ i ].style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
  }
}

for( let i = 0; i < 25; i++ ) {
  const div = document.createElement( `div` );
  
  div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
  div.style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
  body.appendChild( div ); 
}

setInterval( changeRGB, 1000 );
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
  filter: saturate( 200% );
}
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur( 5rem );
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 5rem );
}
div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 25%; min-height: 10%; background-color: #222;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

The function *changeRGB()*:

```
function changeRGB() {
  const divs = body.querySelectorAll( `div` );
  
  for( let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
    divs[ i ].style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
    divs[ i ].style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
  }
}
```

and the *for loop* after it:

```
for( let i = 0; i < 25; i++ ) {
  const div = document.createElement( `div` );
  
  div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
  div.style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
  body.appendChild( div ); 
}
```

contain almost identical lines of code:

```
divs[ i ].style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
divs[ i ].style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
```

and

```
div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
div.style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
```

respectively.

In `changeRGB()` we're manipulating `div`'s that already exist and in the `for` loop we're first creating those `div`'s then manipulating them in the same way. My goal is to refactor this code to make it a little less repetitive.

I need to replace `div` and `divs[ i ]` with something dynamic so I can just call one function and input the proper value here. I'm not sure if the loop complicates things more but I've tried `window[ variable ].style.backgroundColor` etc where `variable` is a dynamic variable but no luck. Possibly implementing it wrong.

**How do I make `changeRGB()` function and `for` loop less repetitive and more concise?**

Comment: This question is likely a better fit at codereview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write another function like this:

```
function applyChange(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
    element.style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
}
```

You would just have to call it like so:

```
function changeRGB() {
  const divs = body.querySelectorAll( `div` );
  
  for( let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
    applyChanges(divs[i]); // <- Call it here
  }
}

for( let i = 0; i < 25; i++ ) {
  const div = document.createElement( `div` );
  
  applyChanges(div); // <- Call it here
  body.appendChild( div ); 
}
```

This way you just pass the div element as a prompt and you can use it dynamically.

Comment: Yo. You forgot to replace `div` with `element` in the new function. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few code-saving ways to approach this. For one, I find using ES6 arrow functions to allow for a more legible approach to multiple functions like this. To directly answer your question, the setting of `backgroundColor` and `transitionDuration` are identical in those 2 different functions, and can be outsourced, as I did below with `applyTransform()`.

There are other space-savers, for example you can shorten something like this:

```
function getRandomRGB() {
  const colors = [];
  
  for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    const  n = getRandomNumber( 100 + 1 );   
    colors.push( n );
  }
  return `rgb(${ colors.join( '%,' )}%)`; 
}
```

into this:

```
const getRandomRGB = () => `rgb(${ [0,1,2].map(n => getRandomNumber( 100 + 1 )).join( '%,' )}%)`
```

Now, shortening code isn't *always* the best option as it can sometimes make it harder to read and maintain. However, I find this result to be easier to read than the original and at the same time it's 16 lines, vs the 32 from the original code.

```js
const body = document.querySelector( `body` );
const getRandomNumber = max => Math.floor( Math.random() * max )
const getRandomRGB = () => `rgb(${ [0,1,2].map(n => getRandomNumber( 100 + 1 )).join( '%,' )}%)`
const changeRGB = () => divs.forEach(applyTransform); 
const applyTransform = div => {
  div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
  div.style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
}
for( let i = 0; i < 25; i++ ) {
  const div = document.createElement( `div` );
  applyTransform(div)
  body.appendChild( div ); 
}
const divs = body.querySelectorAll( `div` )
setInterval( changeRGB, 1000 );
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  filter: saturate( 200%);
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur( 5rem);
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 25%;
  min-height: 10%;
  background-color: #222;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Comment: You can also cache `body.querySelectorAll( 'div' )`  and remove all `return` https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/n678chwk/

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan - great points, and updated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest solution is probably this:

```
//  div.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
//  div.style.transitionDuration = `${ getRandomNumber( 10 ) + 1 }s`;
```

… and this:

```
changeRGB();
setInterval( changeRGB, 1000 );
```

Remove the property generation at creation and run the function manually once if you don't want to wait a second.